# How to execute php redirect without .php extension?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to execute a redirect like this:

```
header("Location: application/controllers/backend");
```

but of course doesn't working 'cause a loop warning appear on the page. Instead, if I execute:

```
header("Location: application/controllers/backend.php");
```

this works but I don't want the `.php` extension. Why? Because I worked on a Route that allow me to load the correct controller in base of the current uri of the server. How I can achieve this?

this is my .htaccess actually:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /AppFolderName/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: `header("Location: application/controllers/backend/ "); ` try set slash after backend.

Comment: sorry and slash before application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a valid url rewrite htaccess you can do this by:

```
header("Location: http://www.yourwebsite.com/application/controllers/backend");
```

and this function to get your full url for your project:

```
function url(){
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])){
        $protocol = ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != "off") ? "https" : "http";
    }
    else{
        $protocol = 'http';
    }
    return $protocol . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}
```

so, redirect code should be:

```
$base_url = url();
header("Location: ".$base_url."/application/controllers/backend");
```

Comment: this give me page generate a redirect loop why?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

or this )

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```